# React native first start of app gives a undefined is not an object, state loads too late

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, axios, state

I'm currently implementing another API call with Axios using redux. I have already the data coming in the view that I want to. But, there is strange behaviour. When I'm loading the data with for example data.userName, the view loads. But when I'm then in another view calling an array, for example data.users.map(....) it gives me every time an undefined is not an object. Also when I console logging the API request it first loads all the views, getting the error and then the data loads (but too late, already getting an error). When I'm removing the data.users.map(...) call, reloading the app that the data loads and then paste the code again in, the app works fine. I'm really stuck here on why I'm loading the data so late.

I'm working with redux and Axios.
Here is the actions file and reducer file:

```js
export const GET_DATA_BEGIN = "GET_DATA_BEGIN"
export const GET_DATA_SUCCESS = "GET_DATA_SUCCESS"
export const GET_DATA_FAILURE = "GET_DATA_FAILURE"

export const getDataBegin = () => ({
    type: GET_DATA_BEGIN
})

export const getDataSuccess = (data) => ({
    type: GET_DATA_SUCCESS,
    payload: {data}
})

export const getDataFailure = (error) => ({
    type: GET_DATA_FAILURE,
    payload: {error}
})

export function getData() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(getDataBegin())
        let ApiUrl = `https://hereissomeurlfordata`
        return axios({
            url: ApiUrl,
            method: 'GET',
            header: {
                Accept: "application/json"
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                dispatch(getDataSuccess(response.data))
                console.log(response)
            } else {
                dispatch(getDataFailure(response.data))
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            dispatch(getDataFailure(error))
        })
    }
}
```

```js
const initialState = {
    data: {},
    error: null,
    loading: false
}

const xchReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case xchActions.GET_DATA_BEGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case xchActions.GET_DATA_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload.data
            }
        case xchActions.GET_DATA_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload.error
            }
            default:
            return state
    }
}

export default xchReducer;
```

And here is the home file

```js
const Home = ({
    getData,
    data
  }) => {
    useFocusEffect(
      React.useCallback(() => {
        getData()
      }, [])
    )

    function renderHeaderContent() {
      return ( <
        View style = {
          {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            ...Platform.select({
              ios: {
                paddingTop: 40
              }
            })
          }
        } >
        <
        View style = {
          {
            marginTop: 10,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignContent: 'center',
            flex: 1
          }
        } >
        <
        Text > {
          data.userName
        } < /Text> <
        /View> <
        /View>
      )
    }


    // here is the error, so when I'm removing this part, reloading the app and then pasting it again it works.  
    const data = {
      datasets: [{
        data: [...data.users.map(d => d.points)],
        strokeWidth: 2 // optional
      }]
    };

    funtion renderChartContent() {
      return ( <
        View >
        <
        LineChart data = {
          data
        }
        width = {
          screenWidth
        }
        height = {
          256
        }
        verticalLabelRotation = {
          30
        }
        chartConfig = {
          chartConfig
        }
        withInnerLines = {
          0
        }
        bezier /
        >
        <
        View >
      )
    }

    return ( <
      View style = {
        {
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: COLORS.white
        }
      } >
      {
        renderHeaderContent()
      } {
        renderChartContent()
      } <
      /View>
    )


    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        data: state.xchReducer.data,
        error: state.xchReducer.error,
        loading: state.xchReducer.loading,
      }
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
        getData: () => {
          return dispatch(
            getData()
          )
        }
      }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

The API response is an array with nested objects: "users":[{"points":22}] and so on.
Also, pre-adding the data is also not working, after that it doesn't update at all. I don't see where I need to change the loading behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the `initialState` of data is `{}`, so when fetching api `data.users` is `undefined`.

You can use `optional chaining` to check.

```
const data = {
  datasets: [{
    data: data.users?.map(d => d.points) || [], // map return new array so don't need spread operator
    strokeWidth: 2 // optional
  }]
};
```

Comment: Hmm now I'm getting an **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'iter[Symbol.iterator]')**

Comment: You can add `|| []` to make sure data of `datasets` alway is an array

Comment: Amazing, now I understand it better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before fetching showing an activity indicator, once fetching completed then hide indicator and showing your content, using state.